# Em um modelo de banco de dados relacional, uma tabela de auditoria deve ter relação com todas as entidades?

Tags: banco-de-dados

O título já diz tudo, em um modelo de banco de dados relacional, uma tabela de auditoria, deve ter relação com todas as entidades que desejo inserir na auditoria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mesmo considerando esta, uma pergunta que pode levar a muitas opiniões, vou deixar minha contribuição.

A minha resposta é **Não** !

Motivos:

1. Acesso a escrita será mais rápido impactando o mínimo possível em sua aplicação já que não haverá validações de constraints
2. Sendo uma tabela de auditoria, você provavelmente armazenará dados que foram deletados (dependendo da sua implementação), esta situação por si só, inviabilizaria as relações.
3. A recupeção de informações nesta tabela será feita de modo pontual em situações de **exceção** e não regra.
4. Evitará locks excessivos em sua aplicação (a verificação de constraints podem causar locks)
5. Qualquer implementação de auditoria que não utiliza referências (constraints) am banco pode ser implementada de forma mais fácil e rápida, inclusive portável (isso vai depender da tecnologia que você esteja usando)